# How to create filtering using SQL statement PHP Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I have one table named as Package. Currently, I want to filter the table actually. Let say the user insert values into variable, for example, from = 2/3/2020 and to = 10/3/2020. Then it will be calculated inside my coding and get the duration of days, resulting noOfdays = 8 days. So, from the duration, it will determined, which packages it belongs within the duration of 8 days.

calculation of days :

```
        $today = Carbon::now();

        $dt1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$departure);
        $dt2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$arrival);

        $noOfDays = $dt1->diffInDays($dt2);
```

The calculation have no error, which when dd($noOfDays), it will result = 8 days.

SQL statement :

```
            $packages = Package::where([
                ['id', '=', $plan],
                ['from', '<=', $noOfDays, 'AND', 'to', '>=', $noOfDays],
            ])
            ->get();
```

Package Table : [image: Package Table]

The error part is, when I filtering, it will get Package 1 and package 2. It supposed to get only the package 2. I think it have something wrong somewhere around the SQL statement. Anyone whoever in this situation before? because logically I think, the SQL part is true already. But it why it filter and get the package 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to separate your two where clause to get what you wanted like this.

```
 $packages = Package::where([
     ['id', '=', $plan], 
     ['from', '<=', $noOfDays], 
     ['to', '>=', $noOfDays]
            ])
 ->get();
```

To be more readable, its good if your code goes like this

```
 $packages = Package::where('id', $plan)
            ->where('from', '<=', $noOfDays)
            ->where('to', '>=', $noOfDays)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your second where statement. Where clause is always using an ADN unlelss you use `orWhere` or nest it in a function.

```
['id', '=', $plan], 
['from', '<=', $noOfDays], 
['to', '>=', $noOfDays]
```

The 4th parameter, that you are passing as an `AND` is not used like you are expecting it to work.

Which results to package1 to be included in your output.